# Getting firebase.json

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-dynamic-links

Using the Firebase console, I created a project and two apps, connected my own domain, and set up a few dynamic links.
Everything works perfectly!

Now I need to add some redirects in the `hosting` section in `firebase.json`. I have installed the CLI for this.

The problem is, I don't know how to get the `firebase.json` file generated by the console in order to modify it.

Comment: The Firebase console doesn't generate a `firebase.json`, so there is nothing to get. Apps, domain/DNS settings, etc are all handled in the console, while things like redirects are handled in `firebase.json`. If you're struggling on how to get a specific setting in your firebase.json, please show what setting it is you're having trouble with and what you already tried.

Comment: My goal is to add a redirect from my dynamic links prefix `example.com` to a specific dynamic link `example.com/link`